# Selenium Python: How to click on a span element with innerText

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

This seems pretty straightforward. I am trying click on a submit button via selenium chrome web driver which obviously quite straight forward. But for some reason, I am not able to do so.

here is how the code look like:-

```
<div class="prettyBtn primaryBtn" onclick="setIsDataAdjustHiddenField();QuoteFormSubmit();return false;"> <span> Get Quote </span></div>
```

attaching image of code snippet.

[image]

so far, I have tried xpath, full Xpath of class "btn", class "prettyBtn primaryBtn".

after no success, I thought of spying them with the class name "find_elements_by_class_name" and still not able to click the button.

here is what I have tried so far:-

via Span Tag:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[text()='Get Quote']").click()
```

via class name:

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("btn").click() 
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("prettyBtn primaryBtn").click()
```

I did look into the documentation and couple of other soultion but so far no luck...I have other web pages where I was able to fill and submit the form but this one. any help or suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *innerText* within the `<span>` contains leading and trailing ***whitespaces*** around it which you have to consider and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *xpath* and *`normalize-space()`*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[normalize-space()='Get Quote']")
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *`contains()`*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., 'Get Quote')]")
  ```

---

To click on the element ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *xpath* and *`normalize-space()`*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[normalize-space()='Get Quote']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *`contains()`*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., 'Get Quote')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: thanks.....completely missed the extra spaces. and what a nice user name @udentected selenium